# How to sort the nested object data in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects

```
    {
    "lion":{
    "age_in_years":"10",
    "name":"king",
    "country":"africa"
    },

    "elephant":{
    "age_in_years":"15",
    "name":"hero",
    "country":"usa"
    },

    "racoon":{
    "age_in_years":"5",
    "name":"thanos",
    "country":"syria"
    },
   }
```

This is the data I'm getting through a web socket in react-native. I want to sort it in ascending order based on the "age_in_years". So the oldest animal's data should be shown at top and  the youngest data at the last.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting object property by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

Comment: @lucifer DId you find any solution or resource for it ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70747479/trying-to-build-an-rdp-app-in-react-native-windows we are also looking for same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sould better work with an array insted of object as below, first map it into array and parse the `age_in_years` and sort it.

```
const obj2Array = Object.entries(<YourObject>).map(([key, value]) => ({...value, _id: key, age_in_years: parseInt(value.age_in_years)}));
const sorted = obj2Array.sort((a, b) => a.age_in_years - b.age_in_years);
```

Then you can use `.reduce` if  you want the object back, nevertheless you can use the sorted array to render it.

Comment: or [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Answer (score 1):

Sort by age in years oldest first

```
// use slice() to copy the array
    var byAge = array.slice(0);
    byAge.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.age_in_years - b.age_in_years ;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in array and make a sort function.

```
const numbers = [info.lion.age_in_years, info.elephant.age_in_years, info.racoon.age_in_years];

const ascNumbers = numbers.sort((a,b) =>  a-b);
```

If you need descending make it like this:

```
 const descNumbers = numbers.sort((a,b) =>  b-a);
```